# Make button clickable only if cursor inside div

Tags: javascript, jquery, onmouseover

I have a div generated via JS with a button in it which I want to make clickable only with a mouse, no manual link following should be possible.

Q1: Is there a way to make the button clickable only if the mouse cursor is inside the div?

```
<div class='modal-body' style='padding-top: 10px'>
<a href='?hash="+hash+"' class='btn btn-success btn-xs cbut "+hash+"'><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-forward "+hash+"'></span></a>
</div>
```

To prevent automated scripts from following the link such as iMacros, I have added the "hash" variable to the link name and class which is now random. 
Even so they can follow the link by adding a * wildcard in the macro script. So I'm outta ideas here.

Q2: Is there a definitive way to restrict link following to mouse only?

Comment: if you click the link then isn't it obvious that cursor is inside the div containing that link?

Comment: Yes, that would be obvious but macro scripts can follow the button's link without clicking on it, which I would like to restrict.

Comment: But what would avoid the macro to just grab href link and do a redirection???

Comment: You want to link to a deep web site or what? There are better ways for human authentication.

Comment: Would iMacros complain about you putting `rel="nofollow"` on the anchor?

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan I think OP wants to avoid macro click, i'm really not sure what it has to do with attribute rel?

Comment: From what I know nofollow is for restricting content from scraper robots such as Google. Not the case here.

Comment: I think your best bet would be to use more robust solution than you could ever imagine, like e.g https://www.google.com/recaptcha/intro/index.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So here's how I made it work for me:

1) Wrap the button inside an invisible element

2) Remove the link and add it via the onclick event

3) Disable the button by default

```
<span style="position:relative;">
<input type="button" onclick="document.location.href='?hash'" class="btn btn-success btn-xs" value="❯❯">
<div style="position: absolute; left: 0px; right: 0px; top: 0px; bottom: 0px; cursor: default; display: none;" id="catch"></div>
</span>
```

4) Remove the invisible element which also triggers the re-enabling of the disabled button from within the target div:

```
$("#catch").mouseover(function (evt) {
    $(this).hide().prev("input[disabled]").prop("disabled", false).focus();
});
```

This way the button can no longer be targeted or activated unless the mouse cursor is placed over it.
I've already beaten current iMacro scripts so this will do for now.

LE: Spoke too soon, seems iMacros was able to target the button quite easily. However I also came up with a quick fix by adding a simple timeout for my function:

```
$("#catch").mouseover(function (evt) {
    var $this = $(this)
    setTimeout(function () {
    $this.hide().prev("input[disabled]").prop("disabled", false).focus();
    }, 1000);
});
```

Thank you for all the inputs here which really kept me going.

Answer (score 1):

Add an event handler on your div with [AddEventListener](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener) and the [mouseover event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/mouseover).

When the event is triggered add the href attr to your <a> link. And remove the attr on mouseout.

Comment: My first thought but what about touch device?

Comment: Touch devices are already restricted so it's not the case here.

Comment: Yea, touch devices will have some troubles...

Maybe you can make a sort of "double-tap" ? Make a first div over your button, that, when clicked disapear. Add a second onlick event on the underlying div (wich one with the link) and, when clicked, add the href attr to the link (or directly start navigation).

Answer (score 1):

Do not use the `<a href inside it>`, use javascript `onclick`, or jquery `on`

```
$('div.modal-body').on('click',function(){
    window.location = "yourlink"
})
```

Comment: But then the macro can click the div

Comment: Exactly, the macro would link to the button instead. I think the best way would be to restrict the button to be clicked only if mouse cursor is inside the said div.

Answer (score 0):

Probably something like this may work.
Basically you watch the cursor position on each click and check if it's inside `$('#demo-box')`. Otherwise you can `e.stopPropagation()` and/or `e.preventDefault()`.

Not sure if this will work because I don't know if macro scripts actually move the mouse. If it does, you can throttle or debounce the clicks shorter than 20-30ms. More info on debouncing [here](https://css-tricks.com/debouncing-throttling-explained-examples/).

```
var $demo_box = $('#demo-box');
var demo_box_width: $demo_box.outerWidth();
var demo_box_height = $demo_box.outerHeight();
var demo_box_offset = $demo_box.offset();

$("#button").on('click', function(e) {
    var relativeX = (e.pageX - demo_box_offset.left);
    var relativeY = (e.pageY - demo_box_offset.top);

    if (relativeX > 0 && relativeY > 0 && relativeX < demo_box_width && relativeY < demo_box_height) {
        alert("X: " + relativeX + "  Y: " + relativeY);
    }
});
```